# Classic thesis + Minionpro

Tags: fonts, classicthesis

How can i use `classicthesis` with `minion pro`? I have tried to put `minion pro` in the options of `classicthesis` but I get an error. I use Windows and TeXLive 2012. Is `minion pro` not in TeXLive as default?

Comment: You have to [buy the Minion pro fonts](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1776). N.B. I'm not promoting the fonts; I don't work for Adobe and don't think they are worth buying! There are lots of good free fonts.

Comment: But if you download the *free* Acrobat Reader, I think you'll get the basic set of Minion Pro fonts.

Comment: @NVaughan --- Indeed; I didn't know that. Installation instructions are [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/).

Answer (score 6):

As @NVaughan points out in the comments, you get the basic set of Minion Pro fonts with Adobe Reader, which you can [download for free](http://www.adobe.com/downloads/). Once the font is installed on your system, `fontspec` should be able to find it, so you could try this if `LuaLaTeX` is an option for you.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Otherwise, you could try the `minionpro` package, which will work with `pdfTeX`. There are installation instructions on the [minionpro ctan page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/).

Comment: This also works with xelatex, of course.

Comment: @Joseph Not with classicthesis (there will be a modified version, soon)

Comment: @Ian Thompson thanks i have try to follow the installation instructions at minionpro ctan page but i have not uderstand this step: You also need some program to convert the OpenType fonts into Type1
format. If you have the LCDF Typetools (http://www.lcdf.org/type/)
installed you can use one of the provided scripts:

o convert.sh  is a Unix script
o convert.bat is a DOS script

Answer (score 3):

I just compiled the following with *xelatex* and it worked fine:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro} %also installable with Acrobat Reader
\begin{document}

\chapter{Teste}

\section{teste}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Of course you do have to install the otf fonts, I don't know what you mean by "basic", because they come with everything you need (old style numerals, basic/rare/historical ligatures, superior/inferior numbers etc.), except optical sizes (caption, display etc.).